# Firebase Auth Email Verification - I need a SDK admin to change email verification user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was working in the email verification. I coded the part to login and create account.
When the user create account, the app init the email auth.

I recive the email and click in link. But my currentUser.emailVerified = false,
even when I log in again (I haven't programmed to save credentials yet).

I'm following this [Auth with FB Using Email Link in JS - firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)

I put the return url with the domain of the vercel that the site is hosted on.

Then it opens the site with some parameters / queries.

I was in doubt if the right thing would be to have to do the firebase function to be this return url and from it change the verification state with the SDK admi, but the doc only says the things I've already done.

**Edit:**

.env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN_FIREBASE=my_domain
```

when app create the account, the app init

```
await sendSignInLinkToEmail(email);
```

function definition:

```
import fireApp from '../fireApp';

async function sendSignInLinkToEmail(email){

  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'https://' + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN_FIREBASE,
    // This must be true.
    handleCodeInApp: true
  };

  return fireApp.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
}

export default sendSignInLinkToEmail;
```

the account create works, the email is sended. But when i click on link to login, currentUser.emailVerified = false, even when I log in again.

> oh, account created but not verified yet. An email will be sent to you. authResponse.user =  Im {N: Array(0), l: "xxxxx", m: "[DEFAULT]", s: "votimsg.vercel.app", a: Ii, …}

And when I login from the dev server, emailVerified: false
(auth response of a new login request, not the first)

Login works, but still not verified.

Comment: Clicking the link in the email should change the verification state of the user. You can *also* do this through the Admin SDK, but it is not required. Can you edit your question to show the code that isn't showing you as verified after clicking the link?

Comment: According to the documentation, it should be like this. I was confused for not having changed. Edits sended

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also note that the code in the screenshot doesn't show anything yet about how you detect that the account is not verified.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to use the formatting properly, I'll update. And yes, this is not yet declared, in this case I used only one email not to enter into this conflict.